# Exposing perf4j performance statistics to JMX does not work

Tags: java, jmx, logback, perf4j

I am trying to expose performance statistics generated by perf4j to JMX using `org.perf4j.logback.JmxAttributeStatisticsAppender` appender, but it does not work.

Following is the relevant portion of my logback.xml

```
    <appender name="fileAppender" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <file>${catalina.base}/logs/perfStats.log</file>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder> 
    </appender>

    <appender name="perf4jJmxAppender" class="org.perf4j.logback.JmxAttributeStatisticsAppender">
        <param name="TagNamesToExpose" value="Import"/>
        <param name="NotificationThresholds" value="ImportMax(&lt;10)"/>
    </appender>

<appender name="CoalescingStatistics"
              class="org.perf4j.logback.AsyncCoalescingStatisticsAppender">
        <param name="TimeSlice" value="1000"/>
    <appender-ref ref="fileAppender"/>
        <appender-ref ref="perf4jJmxAppender"/>
</appender>

<logger name="org.perf4j.TimingLogger" additivity="false">
        <level value="INFO"/>
        <appender-ref ref="fileAppender"/>
        <appender-ref ref="CoalescingStatistics"/>
    </logger>
```

As you will notice, I am appending the performance statistics generated by `AsyncCoalescingStatisticsAppender` to both `fileAppender` and `perf4jJmxAppender`. perfStats.log file gets the follwing row...

```
Tag          Avg(ms)         Min         Max     Std Dev       Count

Import        667.0         667         667         0.0           1
```

...but jconsole shows everything 0 against ImportMean, ImportMax, ImportMin etc.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In the CoalescingStatistics the TimeSlice value is set to 1000 (1s), so in the JMX you will only see the last second.

Try to increase this value and see if it helps.